# Xpages document data not visible in NOTES client

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

X-pages document data not visible in NOTES client but is working perfectly in the browser.
 There is test page, where I have a repeat control, ignores the data in Notes Client and In browser it works perfect,
 below are the images.

**Notes output.**
[image: Notes View]**Browser output**

[image: Browser View]

In the above images the first image is of notes client and 2nd one is of browser.
 Just to verify, I have passed the "View" in the page and the "view" is shown properly in both browser and notes clients.When I written the below exam code to just retrieve the data in test page using the repeat control, The issue is clear in images,

Any suggestion will be appreciated.Thank you.

Edit 1: Source Code ( Have just updated the images for this test)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:div align="center">
        <xp:table style="width:50%;text-align:center">
            <xp:tr>
                <xp:td>
                    <xp:label value="ID" id="label1"></xp:label>
                </xp:td>
                <xp:td>
                    <xp:label value="FORM" id="label2"></xp:label>
                </xp:td>
            </xp:tr>

            <xp:repeat id="crepeat1" rows="30" var="c" indexVar="i">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var v:NotesView = database.getView("all_open_events");
var category = @Name("[Abbreviate]",@UserName());
return v.getAllEntriesByKey(category);
}]]></xp:this.value>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return i +".";}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var doc:NotesDocument = c.getDocument();
return doc.getItemValueString('form');}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:repeat>

        </xp:table>
    </xp:div>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Please update your question with the source code

Comment: I have updates an example with the source code where in lotus notes only data is not visible.you can refer both images namely Notes-Output and Browser-Output respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Very common mistake: you do not specify server in data source. XPages from server work (current server), but for XPiNC you must specify server name or make a local replica of the database (XPages run on local).

Comment: According to the code which is updated now, the image in Notes Output shows the number of documents but could not shows the data, as which is showing in browser.All the pages loads properly but the page where number of records are shown remain blank.The index from the repeat control loads perfect and the data is blank in lotus notes,as like image above.